# How to use generics to handle type-specific configurations in an Action<IBuilder<T>>?

Tags: c#, templates, lambda, delegates

I am trying to implement a complex builder to help my testing context. To do that I refactored my code to have a method :

```
public TestContext Add<T>(Action<IBuilder<T>> configurator) where T : class, new()
{
    IBuilder<T> builder = CreateBuilderOf<T>();
    configurator(builder);
    T item = builder.GetItem();
    RepositoryOf<T>().Insert(item);
    SetCurrent(item);
    return this;
}
```

The problem arises when I need to specify the configuration when calling the method :

```
TestContext.Instance.Add<Person>(personBuilder => ((PersonBuilder)personBuilder).Name("SMITH"));
```

I need to be able to use *type specific* methods in the configurator, which are implemented by the concrete builders, such as :

```
public PersonBuilder : IBuilder<Person>
{
  private Person Item;

  public PersonBuilder() { Item = new Person(); }

  public Name(string mame) { Item.Name = name; }

  public Person GetItem() { return Item; }
}
```

Apparently, passing an `Action<PersonBuilder>` as an `Action<IBuilder<Person>>` is not allowed, even though `PersonBuilder` implements `IBuilder<Person>`, hence the cast.

I would very much like to either :

- Need not to cast *inside the lambda* but rather at the start of it, e.g.
  `(PersonBuilder personBuilder) => personBuilder.Name("SMITH")`, but that boils down to being an instance of `Action<PersonBuilder>` and therefore is equally invalid;
- Use a function such as `BuildSimplePerson(PersonBuilder builder)` in Add's argument : `Add<Person>(BuildSimplePerson)`

I think I can do a type casting through two `BuildSimplePerson`s implementations such as :

```
private void BuildSimplePerson(IBuilder<Person> builder)
{
  BuildSimplePerson(builder as PersonBuilder);
}
private void BuildSimplePerson(PersonBuilder builder)
{
  builder.Name("SMITH");
}
```

But that is not really an elegant solution.

I also realize passing `Action<PersonBuilder>` as an `Action<IBuilder<Person>>` is incorrect because we don't know if the argument to that function will truly be a `PersonBuilder` or any other implementation of `IBuilder<Person>`.

How can I do better ?

Comment: Your problem stems from the simple fact that you treat `IBuilder<Person>` and `PersonBuilder` as the same, when in fact they are not. Your question assumes that `CreateBuilderOf<T>` returns a `PersonBuilder` but it could return anything that implements `IBuilder<Person>` in which case your cast would fail anyway.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes, I realize that. I refactored my question and its title to show what I would like to know in reality : How can I keep a generic Add<T> method and still have a way of having type-specific configurations ?

Comment: @Eregrith: Are you asking if it is possible to have a special `Add` method for `Person`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I think not. I'm sorry if I am not quite clear, it's a bit hard to explain. I would like to keep only one generic Add<T> method as written above, which would receive as a parameter a lambda (or an action in general) to configure such T item. The problem is the configuration contents and methods available should depend on T (person's Name, contract's number ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my comment already states, the problem is that your current code assumes that `CreateBuilderOf<T>` returns a `PersonBuilder` but it could actually return anything that implements `IBuilder<Person>` in which case your cast would fail.

Your code looks like it is generic, but in fact, it is not. You always want to work on the concrete class (`PersonBuilder`) and not on the general interface `IBuilder<Person>`.

My understanding is, that you want one generic `Add<T>` method to avoid having to repeat that code inside it for each type.

Here is my approach:

```
public TestContext Add<T>(IBuilder<T> builder) where T : class, new()
{
    T item = builder.GetItem();
    RepositoryOf<T>().Insert(item);
    SetCurrent(item);
    return this;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
TestContext.Instance.Add<Person>(CreatePersonBuilder().Name("SMITH"));
```

Obviously, you would need to have a `CreateXBuilder` method for each type that you want to be able to add. However, I think you already have this at least implicitly, because I would assume that your `CreateBuilderOf<T>` method is one huge switch statement anyway.

If you don't want to create such methods, another approach to get the builder would be a generic method like so:

```
CreateBuilder<PersonBuilder>()
```

But really, this is actually nothing more than a `new PersonBuilder()`, so you actually could simply go with

```
TestContext.Instance.Add<Person>(new PersonBuilder().Name("SMITH"));
```

The `Configure` method would be very similar:

```
TestContext.Instance.Configure<Person>(id, p => new PersonBuilder(p).Name("SMITH"));
```

This would pass the ID, which the `Configure` method would use to look up the object, which in turn is passed to the callback. So the second parameter of `Configure` would not be a `Action<IBuilder<T>>` but an `Action<T>`.

This approach has another advantage over your existing code:
Your existing code assumes not just that `PersonBuilder` will be the implementation used for `IBuilder<Person>`. No, your code also assumes that it has a constructor without parameters and one which takes a `Person`. These assumptions are impossible for the compiler to verify.
With the code I showed above, a builder implementation could take additional parameters without problems and the compiler would verify that everything is alright.

Comment: I will have a look at that, thanks. My CreateBuilderOf<T> is not a switch, it's an Activator.CreateInstanceOf on a Dictionary<Type, Type>, which is not _that much_ better

Comment: And another problem arises with another method in my context helper : `Configure<T>(object id, Action<IBuilder<T>> configurator)` which brings back T's instance with given id to further edit the object. In that method I need to create an IBuilder<T> with given object as constructor parameter

Comment: That looks great, thanks. I will go with that and accept your answer if I hit no other wall

Comment: I see another advantage with this approach : I can have builders for general purpose similar configurations, which would replace `BuildSimplePerson(IBuilder<Person>)` with `new SimplePersonBuilder()` and that's nice and more pattern-oriented.

Comment: Absolutely. You can encapsulate standard configurations like this